# How word2vec output vectors are used to compute the similarities?

Tags: nlp, distance, similarity, word2vec

I am a bit confused about the interpretation of word2vec output vectors!
If I want to predict the most probable word that will appear after a specific word(w1), can I use the most nearest word to w1?
I mean, a word having the shortest distance from w1 can be interpreted as the next word with the highest probability?

Comment: can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to predict the most probable word that will appear after a specific word(w1),

This is called language modeling

> can I use the most nearest word to w1? 
>   I mean, a word having the shortest distance from w1 can be interpreted as the next word with the highest probability?

no: the nearest word to w1 is the most semantically close word to w1.

Comment: Thank you. How about PMI? Can it reflect the expected closeness?

Comment: it is not a probabilistic output (joint, etc), so there is no link to PMI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found a paper describing the equivalence between shifted PMI and SGNS. "Neural Word Embedding
as Implicit Matrix Factorization", O. Levy, Y. Golberg, NIPS'14